# How to view shared runner queue

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using Gitlab's shared runner. Build has been in 'pending' state for over 20 minutes.

How to debug this? is it something to do with the runner availability or script execution issue.. Is it possible to gain more insight by any means?

[image]

Comment: Even if runner is not shared one this information is useful.

Comment: there's nothing within GitLab itself. You would need access to view the runner logs or monitoring for it. On GitLab.com, there are public dashboards to view performance such as https://dashboards.gitlab.com/d/ci-runners-main/ci-runners-overview

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the UI supports viewing a shared runner's queue. However, this 'pending' state can be caused by things other than a queue.

Check the tags for that pipeline stage against the tags supported by the runners available to the runners activated for your project:

[image: Screencap of Runners screen for a pipeline]

Remember, tags can vary from stage to stage, so it's possible for the first few stages to work before your pipeline is blocked.

Gitlab-ci will indicate 'pending' when a runner cannot be found with tags matching a given stage.

Comment: GitLab will show a message about a 'stuck' job if there are no runners able to run the job - tags don't match, etc. A job that is simply pending without a stuck message is simply waiting for runner capacity to become available.